# Bind Scalar Property at DataEntity(DataEntity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

folks, i am new to C# DataEntity Framework.
I have 2 tables in DB :
 Vehicle with fields id, measurementId. 
 Measurement with fields Id, Name. 
They related as one to one. One vehicle have one measure.

I want to expand entity Vehicles where i want to store MeasurementName field. I've created property MeasurementName, but how i can bind it to Measurement.Name. Is it possible in DataEntity framework ?

I know that i can achive it another way, for example using Entity Linq where i will create new

```
class Test
{
   Id= id,
   Measurement = measurement.Name
};
```

But is it possible to expand DataEntity to have this property ?

Answer (score 2):

Each of the entities in your model is implemented as a [partial class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), meaning the total code that defines the class can exist in multiple files but gets compiled into one object. This makes them highly extensible as you can add properties and functions to the code generated by the Entity Framework designer. Create a new partial class with the same name as your entity in the same namespace and add the custom property like so

```
public partial class Vehicles
{
    public string MeasurementName {
        get {
            return this.Measurement.Name;
        }

        set {
            this.Measurement.Name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

If this answer was helpful to you, please be certain to vote it up or mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes i can do this way, but this property will no be visible in designer when i opem edmx file. How can i map column that i add in edmx designer to the field that in associated table ? (designer generate NOT partial property, so i can't add my code in external file to make property work)

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't. This is why the designer generates partial classes. The system architecture of the designer-generated code dictates you extend the model by creating partial class code, not configure the designer to do things it isn't intended to do.